# Re-use Shimano quick link?

Tags: chain, master-link

Can I use the quick link from my old shimano chain to my new shimano chain? Or the old link will cause any problem? I have to say that no damage is visible  in that old quick link. Both 2x11, same model.

Comment: Related, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/can-you-remove-the-chain-missing-link-too-often, but this already has better answers so won;t vote to close as dupe.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly you want to buy a new chain and re-use your previous masterlink. I'd strongly advise against.

The reason for NOT re-using an old masterlink with a new chain makes sense. Chains are commonly replaced because they are worn. The links are lengthened with time and above a 1% lengthening the chain is considered over the top. The masterlink is worn at the same rate. Now if you use an old masterlink on a new chain you'll have ~110 links of the correct length and one that is longer. The smallest annoyance may residde in a noisy drivetrain. The worst will have the chain skip at each time it reaches the sprockets and once again it reaches the rings.

Comment: The old link may have a place in the tool kit as a get-you-home fix. I say "may" because my 8/9 speed habits might not translate well to 11 speed. It also depends on you carrying the right tools

Answer (score 2):

Shimano's advice is to use a fresh **joining pin** every time.  Ideally you would press out a different rivet, and not use the same hole that the earlier joining pin was pressed into.

Other brands like KMC and Wipperman etc offer **master links**, which can be reused effectively provided they clip together okay.

Always carry a spare master link in your tool kit!

Comment: IMO joining pins are obsolete.  If you're already buying them to put one or two in your tool kit, might as well use one to join the chain when you install it.  That way you can remove the chain to clean it, perhaps even having more than one chain so you can ride while a chain is soaking in a jar of cleaning solvent...

Comment: Shimano uses master links now.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Shimano says do not re-use Quick Links.

> Do not reuse a QUICK-LINK that has been removed. If the QUICK-LINK is reused,
>   there is a risk that it will loosen and become detached, which may result in an
>   accident.

http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-0159A-003-00-ENG.pdf

KMC says the same (about 10 and 11 speed chain versions)

> The Missing Link on chain models X11SL and X11L can not be reused. All other Missing 
>   Links can be reused between 2-3 times per life cycle of the chain. If you purchase a
>   replacement chain, the used Missing Link should not be reused and is not
>   interchangeable. Missing Links offer riders ease of maintenance and quick chain 
>   replacement when there is an emergency on the road or trail.

http://kmcchain.us/faqs/

SRAM 10 and 11 speed PowerLock links should not be re-used either.

https://www.bikeradar.com/us/mtb/gear/article/trail-tech-mastering-master-links-36757/

Comment: On the European market, KMC on the other hand have 2 types of 10 and 11-speed links. Those that must (should) not be re-used in the life-cycle of the same chain and those that may be re-used.

Comment: @Carel That's interesting, do you have a link for a product page or description?

Comment: Linkt KMC's page http://www.kmcchain.de/connector-road_cross

Comment: Even for its reusable master links KMC does not recommend to re-open them more than a few times. I had it written on the one 10-speed I had installed recently.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov of course! Opening and closing the link wears the edges that keep the two parts of the link together. I'd do it three times in the life time of a link. But then the problem new link on old chain may also cause trouble!